# Turn on camera light but not camera

Tags: camera

Is it possible to turn on the light that indicates that the camera (on a MacBook) is on without turning on the camera? (Then it could be used as an indicator for something else.)

Answer (score -1):

A couple years ago there was rumours about malware being able to run the camera without having the light on.  Both LED and Camera are driven by the Apple SMC (System Management Controller) and are linked together far below OSX user level.

Since then Apple most probably have put extra efforts to avoid usage of one without the other.

Comment: The OP isn't asking how to use the camera on the MacBook without triggering the LED beside it, but how to trigger the LED without using the camera.

Comment: I tried to prove that the camera and LED are linked together on a hardware level.   If you don't see how that's related, just downvote.

Comment: Upvoted because the answer is _not_ irrelevant. I gather that you’re suggesting that separating the two may be a security issue, and that the short answer to the original question is probably not.